# nginx redirect dynamic page urls

Tags: nginx, redirect

After changing the URL structure of my site I am getting a lot of 404 not found errors. Can some one point me into the right direction how to change certain page urls to a single page url using **nginx**.

Here are some examples of the pages which should permanently be redirected to the location **domain.com/gallery/**. Since I have more than 50 domain page urls which should be redirected to only one single page I have tried redirecting the dynamic urls by using (.+)

Sample Urls which should be redirected to one singe page...

```
domain.com/forum/photoplog/file.php?n=1149&w=l
domain.com/forum/photoplog/file.php?n=463&w=l
domain.com//forum/photoplog/file.php?n=464&w=l
```

My attempt to redirect **all** dynamic urls after **/photoblog/** to a single page **/gallery/**, which did not work out.

```
location = /forum/photoplog/(.+) {
rewrite ^ /gallery/? permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (tested on Nginx 1.2.6 - Linux):

```
location /forum/photoplog/ {
   rewrite ^/forum/photoplog/(.+) /gallery/$1? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Unfortunately I am still getting the 404 not found error message.

Comment: on your browser, the URL is changed from domain.com/forum/photoplog/file.php?n=1149&w=l  to  domain.com/gallery/file.php?n=1149&w=l   ?    If you get an 404 error, it's maybee due to your location /gallery (remove = and (.+) )  settings. Please post your nginx  conf file.

Comment: It is somehow not working out. I have a lot of dynamic dead links from my old gallery in my webmaster tools error log. All dead URL's should only link to one single page since the content is not available anymore. (e.g. this link domain.com/forum/photoplog/file.php?n=1149&w=l should change to domain.com/gallery/ just like all the other dynamic photoplog links should point to domain.com/gallery/ Check out my nginx.conf file at http://pastebin.com/fuPN5uFY

Comment: your rewrite rules are not correct. when you do rewrite ^ / permanent;  without $1, you lost everything. see my answer. or use location /forum/ { rewrite ^/forum/(.+) /$1? permanent; }

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. It just won't work. Maybe I will have to upgrade the nginx server.

Comment: if your Nginx is outdated, why not install the latest stable version ? (With the PCRE extension to allow regex in config file)